# CSRF Verification error appeared after I changed DNS

Tags: django

I have been using Django successfully for a few days now. I was running my django application on an Amazon Web Service machine. 
I was assigned some arbitrary DNS name that looked like this: http://ec2-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
My Django app was working find with my model and several views with templates.

Last night, I went out and bought a real DNS name from register.com and have that DNS name now pointing to my django application.
Since I made that change however, when I submit my django form, I get the following CSRF error:

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

I tried clearing the cookies in my browser, but that didn't help. I even tried it from other machines that I had never tried before. But still the same problem.
Why did assigning a new DNS name for this IP address cause this CSRF error? And how do I get rid of it?

My form:

```
<form action="/forgotUserName2" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

<label for="id_email">E-mail:</label></th><td><input id="id_email" type="text" class="required" name="email" maxlength="75" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-cookie-domain) setting in your `settings.py` file to your new domain name.

Also, an aside, your action is named `/forgotUserName2`. Methods and functions in python usually look like this: `forgot_user_name_2` ie; snake_cased. Also, URLs within django should always end with a trailing slash: `/forgot_user_name_2/`.

Comment: I set my CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN to "percephany.com". Is that right?
or should it be "www.percephany.com" or ".percephany.com" ?

I'm still getting the CSRF error.

When I examined Google Chrome's cookies, I see:
two csrftoken entries with the same token value. However one's domain is "percephany.com" and the other's is ".percephany.com"

Comment: Actually, I cleared out the cookies and tried again.
The problem remains. But for percephany.com, I see only 1 csrftoken cookie. It's domain is ".percephany.com"